# How to find ic by truth table

Tags: microcontroller, pic

How to find ic by truth table ? I have input output truth table but i can't find suitable ic. What are website of ic finder by truth table ?

Comment: ICs aren't available in every possible combination of logic function and I'm not aware of anything like you're seeking. Perhaps if you wanted to share the truth table someone could suggest suitable types of IC(s) that could be used and a way to go about designing the logic.

Comment: Which is 7 segment encoder IC ? When no inputs 7 segment display will off.

Comment: If you are looking for a 7-segment display controller chip, do not ask for a website that finds ICs, _ask for a good 7-segment display controller that fits your requirements_. In that new question, demonstrate at least some of your own research into the subject.

Answer (score 5):

ICs aren't available in every possible combination of logic function and I'm not aware of anything like you're seeking to find devices by truth table. The typical approach would be to use basic [logic gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gates) such as `AND`, `OR`, `XOR` and `NOT` and their various derivatives to make a circuit that meets your requirements. From there a few choices to build it are:

- Use basic logic ICs such as the [7400 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series) and [4000 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4000_series) that contain a handful of gates.
- Use a PAL, CPLD or FPGA in order of lower to higher density that can be programmed with your own logic design.

You mentioned a 7-segment encoder in a comment, some of the 7400 series devices were produced for that specific purpose so it might be worth checking the list of devices in that series to see if they are still available and meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use an EEPROM chip. With, say, 8 bits of address and 8 bits of data (256 bytes of storage), you can have up to 8 completely custom truth tables computed simultaneously, from up to 8 inputs.